# WARNING: Failed to scan text length or time type for column

Tags: sas

I'm running SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M5 x64_7PRO platform on Windows 6.1.7601.

I'm attempting to import an Access table with over 30,000 records that has 7 columns. One of the columns, "Results", contains data exceeding 4,000 characters (both numeric and text) for certain records. When using the code below,

```
 PROC IMPORT OUT= ED_Notes_July2019
        DATATABLE= "ED_Notes_Import" 
        DBMS=ACCESS REPLACE;
 DATABASE="J:\EMTC\JMC\PECARN Registry\ED Documents Reports\2019\Month\Docs_Jul.accdb"; 
 SCANMEMO=YES;
 USEDATE=NO;
 SCANTIME=YES;
 RUN;
```

I get the following, "WARNING: Failed to scan text length or time type for column RESULT." In doing a little bit of research online, I only find potential solutions involving Excel (http://support.sas.com/kb/33/257.html). Is anyone aware of a solution applicable to Access?

I also have the data stored within SQL table (index space 836 MB; data space 50,000 MB; row count 8,948,138) but it takes hours to import that data from there using the code below:

```
 LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='SQL Server' schema=dbo; 
 data ED_Notes_Master; 
 set sql.ED_Notes_Master;
 if datepart(RESULT_DT_TM) > '01JUL2019'd;
 run;
```

Comment: Have you tried  "length Results $ 4500". With a column field over 4000 characters might be the issue.

Comment: I have vague recollections of this being limited by the ODBC connection type. Do you have SAS ACCESS to PCFILES or just ODBC?

Comment: @Reeza sorry but how can I determine if I have SAS access to PCFILES or ODBC?

Comment: PROC PRODUCT_STATUS will tell you what you have licensed and installed. PROC SETINIT will tell you what you have licensed.

Comment: @Reeza I have access to ODBC, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is most likely not being pushed to the server side by the automatic features of the `ODBC` engine.

Try replacing the `if` with a `where` statement and a datetime literal:

```
where RESULT_DT_TM > '01JUL2019:0:0'DT;
```